# Is the relative clause always an adjunct/modifier of the antecedent?

Tags: relative-clauses, modifiers, complements, antecedents, adjuncts

The first two sentences mean the same thing, and so do the last two.

> (1) She's obviously the person **to finish the job**.
>
> (1') She's obviously the person **who should finish the job**.
>
> (2) She was the first person **to finish the job**.
>
> (2') She was the first person **who finished the job**.

The emboldened clauses are all relative clauses, and those in (1) and (2) are infinitival relative clauses.

In general, the relative clause is not a complement but an adjunct/modifier of the antecedent. In (1) and (1'), for example, both the relative clauses are adjuncts/modifiers of the antecedent *person*. Clearly, they are not complements of *person*.

In (2), however, it seems that *first* licenses *to finish the job*. If so, is the infinitival relative clause complement of the antecedent *first person*? Or is it still adjunct/modifier of the antecedent just as it is in (1).

How about (2')? Does *first* licenses *who finished the job*? Is the infinitival relative clause complement or adjunct/modifier?

In short, is the relative clause always an adjunct/modifier of the antecedent? Or is it sometimes a complement of the antecedent?

Comment: The first thing that comes to my mind is that there's already plenty of mystery about the _should_ with relative infinitives. The second thing is that you didn't mention object relatives, which are more common than subject ones; _She's the first person one should talk to/the first person to talk to about that_. The facts seem the same, though. I wouldn't worry about licensing; that's not really syntactic conditioning.

Comment: @JohnLawler What do you mean you wouldn't worry about licensing? Do you mean the infinitival relative clause in (2) is still an adjunct regardless of it being licensed by _first_?

Comment: I don't understand infinitival relative clauses; but to the extent they represent tensed relative clauses (modal or no), I should think that whatever category label you want to apply to one, you should apply to the other. As to _first_: (a) it's a superlative and has very specific scope; (b) I would say that _first_ modified the N' _person who finished the job_, not either the noun or the clause.

Comment: @JohnLawler (a) Since when have ordinal numbers become superlatives? (b) Since _first_ follows _the_ (determiner), it's not a determiner but simply a modifier. So _first person who finished the job_ is clearly N'. Now, in this N', what's the antecedent of the relative clause? Is it _first person_ or _person_? You seem to be saying that it's the latter, but I'm not sure why the former cannot be the antecedent.